# PHPExcel вставка изображения в примечание

Tags: php, phpexcel

Как посредством PHPExcel вставить изображение в примечание xlsx файла(заливка), то есть, чтобы вместо заливки цветом, была заливка изображением:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('E13')->getFillColor()->setRGB('EEEEEE');
```

в EXCELе это:

```
ActiveCell.AddComment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (ImaFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Выводим картинку
$objDrawing  = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing(); 
$objDrawing->setPath('картинка.png'); 
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1'); 
//$iDrowing->setWidth(30); 
//$iDrowing->setHeight(30);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(35);
//$iDrowing->setRotation(25);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```